# NullPointerException : android editText

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I've been following this [this tutorial](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html) to create a date picker , but I keep having a nullpointerexception when setting the value of edit_text, here some parts of my code :

```
// Update demo edittext when the "OK" button is clicked
            ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDateTimePicker.clearFocus();
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String result_string = mDateTimePicker.getMonth()
                                    + "/"
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getDay())
                                    + "/"
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getYear())
                                    + "  "
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getHour())
                                    + ":"
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker
                                            .getMinute());

                            edit_text.setText(result_string);
                            mDateTimeDialog.dismiss();
                        }
```

and here I declare the edit_text :

```
EditText edit_text ;

        static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newcase, container,
                    false);

            // final View formView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mform,container,
            // false);

            final LinearLayout formbis = (LinearLayout) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.formbis);

            /*
             * 
             * ****************
             */
    EditText edit_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

            ....
```

but the initalization of the edit_text seems to be 'not used'.

All of this is inside a fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing your `EditText` wrong. `edit_text` is an instance variable.

Remove the EditText from this line:

```
EditText edit_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

So it looks like this:

```
edit_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText edit_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

Here you are creating a local variable `edit_text`which is visible within the scope of the `onCreateView()` method. You need to initialize the instance variable `EditText edit_text ;` as :

```
edit_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

Without initializing it, by default `` `EditText edit_text ; `` is a `null` reference.